# Magento 2 - get scopeconfig values

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I'm working on Magento 2.

But couldn't find the solutions for getting scopeconfig values in layout xml files.

In magento 1.x, using like below.

```
<block type="cms/block" ...>
    <action method="..." ifconfig="config_path/config"></action>
</block>
```

In magento 2, how to use "ifconfig" in the layout xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's same with magento 1.x.

You can use like below.

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" ifconfig="catalog/seo/search_terms" name="search-term-popular-link">
```

Comment: How to use it in the phtml files?

Answer (score 2):

### You can simply use like as

```
<block class="Ced\Abhinay\Block\Account\Active" ifconfig="ced/account/activation" name="ced_account_activation">
```

Where

> Ced = Your Namespace
>
> Abhinay = Your Module Name

Answer (score 1):

Method1: Using Object Manager

```
<?php
     $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
     $conf = $objectManager
             ->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')
             ->getValue('section_id/group_id/field_id');
             echo $conf;
?>
```

Method2: Using Helper

Create Data.php inside Helper folder of your module and write below code inside it.

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
public function getConfig($config_path)
{
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
        $config_path,
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );
}
}
?>
```

You can call this helper inside your phtml file by below code-

```
<?php
 $value=$this->helper('Megha\Menu\Helper\Data')->getConfig('section_id/group_id/field_id');
   echo $value;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below.

```
<block class="Magento\Rss\Block\Feeds" ifconfig="rss/config/active" name="head_rss">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get directly scop config value into phtml file using below code.

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $conf = $objectManager
            ->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')
            ->getValue('group/field/value');
```

Second Way to Created function for getting configuration values in your custom module's helper

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
public function getConfig($config_path)
{
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
        $config_path,
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );
}
```

}

Then you can get the configuration values to call this function in any phtml files.

```
$this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helper\Data')->getConfig('section/group/field');
```

**Note:** Please refer below links.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84481/magento-2-how-to-get-the-extensions-configuration-values-in-the-phtml-files*emphasized text*